# Approximate continuous mapping by smooth mappings on manifold(Bott, Tu book)

Tags: general-topology, analysis, differential-topology

So I was looking at the proof given in Bott, Tu "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology" of how to approximate continuous mapping by smooth mappings between manifolds. It is Proposition 17.8 on Page 213.

The Proposition goes as:

Every continuous map $f:M\rightarrow N$ between two manifolds is continuously homotopic to a differentiable mapping.

The proof basically goes as: First assume $N=\mathbb{R}$, then it is more or less obvious. Then for general $N$, by invoking Whitney Embedding Theorem, $N$ can be embedding into a $\mathbb{R}^k$ when $k$ is big enough. That is, $\exists g:N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$smooth. Then the author made a remark which I don't see why:

If $g\circ f:M\rightarrow g(N)\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ is homotopic to a differentiable mapping, so is $f=g^{-1}\circ (g\circ f):M\rightarrow N$.

Here is the part I don't see why. How does the the author guarantee that the differentiable mapping homotopic to $g\circ f$ won't assume value in $\mathbb{R}^k\setminus g(N)$, thus making it impossible to take it back by applying $g^{-1}$.

I hope I am clear enough about my question. Any comment or reference to proofs of the same theorem would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully this is helpful. It is an excerpt from Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

[image: Picture]

Comment: I saw this proof before. But since I am not aware of Whitney approximation theorem or the smooth retraction mentioned in the proof, I skipped it. Bott, Tu's book's proof requires less background knowledge. But as I explained, I found I can't get around that point. I still wish that someone might be able to tell me how it is possible.

Comment: I've actually been looking at this proof at a more careful level. And I realized Tubular Neighborhood and Retraction are exactly the tools that Lee used to solve the question I have. I guess I will choose @Potato as the best answer if nobody gives a better answer in the following couple of days! Thanks man, @Potato!

Comment: @henryforever14 No problem. Bott and Tu is very difficult book -- I wish you luck!